# How to get this simple ZF2 view resolver to work

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Here's my code:

```
$renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
$resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack(array(
    'script_paths' => array(
        '/module/B2bCore/view/b2b-core/std-email')));
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);

$view = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$view->setTemplate("{$this->template}.phtml")->setTerminal(true);
$content = $renderer->render($view);
```

This throws an error.  For example, when the value of $this->template is `org/invite.phtml` I get the following:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "org/invite.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

My file path and name is as follows:

```
/module/B2bCore/view/b2b-core/std-email/org/invite.phtml
```

I see that the examples in the manual specify the script paths using the `__DIR__` magic constant.  I would prefer to stick away from this and reference everything from the application root (which is set per the sample module index.php file).  I think that the config above is in line with this, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really supposed to write paths relative to your application in your ZF2 modules.

In your example, `"/module..."` is recognized as an absolute path (starts with a `/`), and `realpath()` obviously reduces it to `false`, which is why you see an exception message telling you something about `"org/invite.phtml"`.

Since your package/module contains the views that are to be rendered, you should always use `__DIR__` to reference them, as you don't know what the application's path is (from a "vendor" perspective).

Your view resolver should probably be instantiated with something like following (adjust the path):

```php
$resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack([
    'script_paths' => [
        __DIR__ . '/../../view/b2b-core/std-email'
    ]
]);
```